# I cant import from this module using command prompt windows 32bit

Tags: python, module, python-import

```
class Bird :
   '''A base class to define bird properties.'''

   count = 0
   
   def __init__(self , chat ) :
   
      self.sound = chat 

      Bird.count += 1


   def talk (self ) :
 
      return self.sound

from Bird import*
print('\nClass Instance Of:\n', Bird.__doc__)


polly = Bird('Squawk,squawk!')

print('\nNumber Of Birds:', polly.count)
print('Polly Says:', polly.talk() )

harry = Bird('Tweet,tweet!')

print('\nNumber Of Birds:', harry.count)
print('Harry says:', harry.talk() )
```

Comment: so what precisely is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also refer to the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098).

Comment: i get this error message once I try to import the first script                            
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "instance.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Bird import*
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bird'

Answer (score 0):

Is the Bird class in the same file as the import statement?
If so you won't need to import it.
Import is only for modules that are inside other files.

To access Bird's contents in this case you can just create an instance and use that